# R file.copy copy.mode backward compatibility

Tags: r

In R 2.13 file.copy introduced a new copy.mode argument that affects the permissions of the output of the copy.  As a result, a program that works with R 2.n where n < 13 may no longer work.  I discovered this on Solaris.

If dl.txt is has 444 permissions, and the user's umask is 002,

```
file.copy("dl.txt", "k.txt")
```

used to create k.txt with 664 permissions.  Now it has 444.  This behavior can be overridden by adding copy.mode=FALSE to every copy statement in every program, just in case it might matter.  But if you do this, and are using an older version of R, you get a fatal runtime error.

Is there some way to globally change the default behavior in the newer versions of R? Or some other way to preserve backward compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override it in some global area, e.g. the `.Rprofile`:

```
if( getRversion() > 2.13 ) {
  file.copy <- function(...) { base::file.copy(..., copy.mode=FALSE) }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work for me.  After changing V to v and adding an extra right paren, it seemed to cause R to loop.  It had taken about 30 seconds of cpu time when I killed it, and the file I was copying was only 11 bytes long.

Comment: I updated my answer. If we explicitly call `base::file.copy` then I think it should work. I think it may have just been recursing on itself (oops)